# Garbage in debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I found strange `Visual Studio 2010` behavior while debugging project. Variable string `s` was initialized with `""`, but debugger shows garbage. Debug point is in the second line of `s` initialization.

[image]

if I do `cout<<s`, it prints normal value - not garbage.

One more immage to be shure where is breakpoint 
[image]

In other project places debugger works fine. Procedure where I have garbage is win message handler. 
Message was transmitted from same project other thread.

```
LRESULT CMainWindow::OnMessageAuthorise(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
string s= ""; 
...
}
```

What is wron?

UPD:
Problem is in profile Debug/Release selection. If I choose Release I have these garbage on variables. Why it is so?

Comment: Where is the breakpoint?

Comment: in the second line of s initialization (if(ad.t...

Comment: How about printing it out there?

Comment: You don't need `= "";` for `std::string`. By default it should initialize to an empty string. Not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: it prints out normal value (not garbage)

Comment: The yellow highlight indicating the currently executing line of code is not visible in your screenshot (though you may have configured Visual Studio not to show it). Are you sure the active stack frame actually lies in that code? Otherwise, you may be inspecting another (uninitialized) `s` variable in another stack frame.

Comment: I have added som additional info in problem description with picture that shows stack frame

Comment: A good practice is to use String s = String.Empty;

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: unless you're willing to inspect disassembly, you can't set watches in release builds.  That's what debug builds are for.

Longer answer:  In release builds many optimizations can make the mapping of a variable name to a memory address much harder. The simplest case - the variable might have *no* memory address: it can be saved only in registers.  Traditional generation of PDB files (the files that hold - among others - this mapping info) didn't even try to cope with the difficulties emanating from optimizations, but since VS2012 [a new switch takes a substantial step in that direction](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/debugging-optimized-codenew-in-visual-studio-2012/).